# What constraint height to use for UILabel with numberOfLines=2? (using [NSString sizeWithFont...])

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, nsstring, uilabel

How to determine constrainedToSize.height to use in [NSString sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:...] for a UILabel with a limited number of rows?

Constraint height below is unlimited (MAXFLOAT), but what to use for the maximum height of a label when limited to X number of lines?

```
UILabel * label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.numberOfLines = 2;
label.text = @"Some really long text";

// what to use instead of MAXFLOAT?
CGSize constrainSize = CGSizeMake(285, MAXFLOAT);

CGSize size = [label.text
               sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0]
               constrainedToSize:constrainSize
               lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping
               ];
```

Many thanks!

Comment: The code that you have is right. What do you think is wrong with it?

Comment: @matt The code will return a size that fits the text is as many lines as it needs which could be more than the 2 lines he is looking for.

Comment: The idea of constrainSize height to be infinity is to allow the label to grow to any height. If you know it can only be finite size, just set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know you want the label to be 2 lines, then use:

```
CGFloat maxHeight = label.font.lineHeight * 2;
CGSize constrainSize = CGSizeMake(285, maxHeight);
```